# PHP Regular Expression: How to find every < that doesn't belong to a valid HTML Element

Tags: php, regex, domdocument

Is it possible to find all < (lower than triangle bracket) (and >) in PHP that do not belong to valid HTML Elements (could be stored in an array)? I'd like to mask these characters automatically.

Example:

```
$html = '<div class="some class"><pre>5 < 8</pre></div>';

$triangles = getAllTriangles($html);
```

where getAllTriangles($html) results in only **one** triangle (the one between 5 and 8), so it could be masked with < while the others stay as the are to get the right output.

EDIT:
Actually, the problem I have results from the PHP DOMDocument and it's parser.
If I'd like to read a html string as above

```
$html = '<div class="some class"><pre>5 < 8</pre></div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$output = $doc->saveHTML();
```

This will result in

```
<div class="some class"><pre>5 </pre></div>
```

because of the triangle. For that, I'd like to mask these characters automatically. I'd would be a real problem to mask the in the html strings I'm reading. After all triangles are masked, I could use DOMDocument as I'd like to.

What I really want to have is a regular expression that replaces all triangles that don't belong to html-tags, the output in the example above would be:

```
<div class="some class"><pre>5 &lt; 8</pre></div>
```

More examples:

```
input:    <pre>while i < 10 do....</pre>
output:   <pre>while i &lt; 10 do....</pre>

input:    <div><button-1></div>
output:   <div>&lt;button-1&gt;</div>
```

Comment: See this post: [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Comment: I guess my answer does not answer the question 100% but to get more accurate answers, you need to specify exactly what kind of output you expect to get (a string, a count, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You could try to strip all html tags from your string and use simple string functions to find the `<` and `>` characters on the result:

```
$html = '<div class="some class"><pre>5 < 8</pre></div>';
$no_html = strip_tags($html);
var_dump($no_html);
$count = substr_count($no_html, '<');
var_dump($count);
```

See the [example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HQipVR).

**However**, please note that this approach may fail as your "html" string is not valid html as the `<` and `>` that are not part of html tags should be encoded as `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

If you need something different than the count, I would recommend using an html parser instead of regular expressions and possibly use regular expressions on the contents you find with the html parser. The same note about non-valid html applies here as well.

Comment: Would it be possible to replace the triangles in $no_html and then put the strings back into $html? I can't see a solution for that.

Comment: @user3166248 You would have to use an html parser and use string functions (or regular expressions) on the contents, but it might not work consistently with non-valid html.